# Помогите решить задачу по Objective C

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, apple

Есть программа по созданию таблицы простых чисел.

```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        int p,d,cases;
        for (p=1; p<=100; ++p) {
            cases = 1;
            for (d = 2; d<p; ++d)
                if (p % d == 0)
                    cases = 0;
                if (cases != 0)
                    NSLog(@"%i",p);
                }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

По заданию нужно
Программа 6.10 в ряде случаев работает неэффективно. Например, это касается проверки четных чисел. Поскольку любое четное число больше 2 не может быть простым, программа могла бы пропускать все четные числа и как возможные простые числа, и как возможные делители. Внутренний цикл for тоже работает неэффективно, поскольку для р все время выполняется деление на все значения d от 2 до р-1. Чтобы избежать этой неэффективности, можно добавить значение cases в условия for. Тогда вы можете задать выполнение цикла for до тех пор, пока не найден делитель и значение d меньше р. Модифицируйте программу 6.10, чтобы внести эти два изменения, затем выполните эту программу, чтобы проверить ее работу.

Получается так вроде бы

```
for (d = 2; d<p || cases == 1; ++d)
```

??  Как его в цикл добавить если перед циклом мы объявляем значение переменной cases 1; когда начинается цикл то переменная cases по умолчанию 1, а мне нужно выходить из цикла когда значение 1. Выходит нужно изначально объявить значение cases 0 и в условие проверять когда оно будет равно 1?
А по поводу того
Поскольку любое четное число больше 2 не может быть простым, программа могла бы пропускать все четные числа и как возможные простые числа, и как возможные делители.

Это выходит `(p % 2 == 0 || p % 5 == 0)` я правильно сделал?

Comment: Ну и что тут не понятно? чтобы проверять только нечетные числа сделайте шаг в цикле равным 2. внутренний for надо обрывать, как только подтвердилось, что число не является простым. кроме того, можно посмотреть википедию и узнать, что для любого числа максимальный делитель не превышает квадратный корень этого числа и оптимизировать алгоритм.

Answer (score 1):

Ну допустим так (2 просто выводится и в алгоритме не участвует)

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        int p,d,cases;
        NSLog(@"2");
        for (p=3; p<=100; p+=2) {
            cases = 1;
            for (d = 3; d<sqrt(p); d+=2)
                if (p % d == 0) {
                    cases = 0;
                    break;
                }
            if (cases != 0)
            NSLog(@"%i",p);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так у Вас все `p` будут печататься (так что `cases` все же нужна).

Comment: кстати да, исправил